# Joda-Time library is not working on Android 5 with Proguard enabled

Tags: java, android, proguard, jodatime

This problem is only occurring in Android 5. The app crashes write at the point and i create a new `DateTime` object like:

```
mStartTime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
```

Crash Report is:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "long boq.f()"
   at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicYearDateTimeField.(BasicYearDateTimeField.java:46)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicChronology.assemble(BasicChronology.java:273)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.GregorianChronology.assemble(GregorianChronology.java:197)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.AssembledChronology.setFields(AssembledChronology.java:323)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.AssembledChronology.(AssembledChronology.java:102)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicChronology.(BasicChronology.java:131)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicGJChronology.(BasicGJChronology.java:75)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.GregorianChronology.(GregorianChronology.java:153)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.GregorianChronology.getInstance(GregorianChronology.java:133)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.GregorianChronology.getInstance(GregorianChronology.java:99)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.GregorianChronology.(GregorianChronology.java:70)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.GregorianChronology.getInstanceUTC(GregorianChronology.java:80)
   at org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology.(ISOChronology.java:59)
   at org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.(BaseDateTime.java:73)
   at org.joda.time.DateTime.(DateTime.java:184)
   at com.znapo.photo_sharer.asynctasks.GetAllSessionTask.onPostExecute(GetAllSessionTask.java:149)
   at com.znapo.photo_sharer.asynctasks.GetAllSessionTask.onPostExecute(GetAllSessionTask.java:1)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

My Complete Proguard Configuration file is:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.**
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontpreverify
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
#-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}


-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

#for support library
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v13.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v13.** { *; }

#for retracing obfuscated stack traces
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.tweetstudio.tweet_studio_app.dto.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------


##--------For Google Play services-------------##

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

##---------- End: proguard configuration for google play ---------------

##---------- proguard configuration for joda-time ---------------

-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
```

Following jars are added to the build path for Joda-Time:

```
joda-time-2.7.jar
joda-convert-1.7.jar
joda-time-2.7-javadoc.jar
```

After converting the `joda-convert-2.7.jar` to `zip` and exploring the line 46 of `BasicYearDateTimeField` i am seeing this line of code:

```
super(DateTimeFieldType.year(), chronology.getAverageMillisPerYear());
```

Comment: "This problem is only occurring in Android 5", means it isn't happening in...?

Comment: Yes on the devices running OS below Andriod 5, app is working fine.

Comment: Tested on Android 4.4.4 and 4.0.2, the app is working fine even with proguard enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the line:-

```
-keep class org.joda.** { *; }
```

to your proguard config. This will prevent the code from joda library to be removed. Adding this line increased the apk size by 2.8 KB only for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this github Joda-Time Library [Git Hub Joda Time](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a peek at some documentation will shed some light:

> [AbstractMethodError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)
>
> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

Something promised that "long boq.f()" would be implemented and it lied.  That should only be possible at run time if something that should have been recompiled wasn't recompiled.

I would write a simple stand alone program that used joda-time and `new DateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault());` see if the problem was easy to reproduce.  If it is you've isolated the problem to that version of joda-time.  See if rolling back to an older one makes the problem go away.

You could also just recomiple joda-time and anything that talks to joda-time.  Doing this should at the very least turn this run time error into a compile time error.  That should make it easy to see what is wrong.

Comment: But what would be solution then?

Comment: Um recompile? Anyway, when I look at http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/xref/org/joda/time/chrono/BasicYearDateTimeField.html line 46 is just `iChronology = chronology;`  So I'm thinking I'm looking at the wrong version.  What does your version have on line 46?

Comment: line 46 of `BasicYearDateTimeField` in my version: `super(DateTimeFieldType.year(), chronology.getAverageMillisPerYear());`

Comment: Actually i tried several time to export the apk after clean/build, so i think recompile will not work.

Comment: Kinda has me stumped.  I expected the call to cross into another package/dependency that might have changed versions independently.  Both of those calls are in the same package.

Comment: Hmm I lied. org.joda.time.DateTimeFieldType has a slightly different package than org.joda.time.chrono.BasicYearDateTimeField.  Any chance one got updated/recompiled without the other?

Comment: Actually how do you want me to recompile?

Comment: I'm trying to verify what's in sync with what version.  Something is out of sync and I'm trying to eliminate possibilities.

Comment: Did your older / working versions of your code use the same version of joda-time?

Comment: Yes for sure. It is using the same jar files

Comment: And everything you've developed since then was developed against the same version of joda-time?

Comment: Yes. I am testing the same apk on Android 5, 4.4.4, 4.1.2.